# Copy files to the tomcat webapps folder in Docker container using Docker-compose

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a scenario like i had to copy couple of configuration files to the tomcat webapps folder which exists inside the docker container. Here is my dockerfile which i use

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.82-jre8
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat
COPY /app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
EXPOSE 8080
COPY tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/
```

Once we run the docker, it actually does the following

1. It actually copy app.war to the tomcat webapps folder and extracts to an folder named "app"
2. Docker will try to start the tomcat server.

I want to copy my configuration file to the extracted war file which is inside the tomcat webapps folder. Here is the location of the property look like
tomcat_home/webapps/app/conf/services.properties before starting the tomcat server

I am having a challenge of copying this property file to the corresponding folder before starting the tomcat caontainer.

I am not sure how to do this using docker-compose.  Whether is this really possible in docker-compose.yml or using dockerfile ? Any answers would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Either you can use `volume:` inside services part of `docker-compose.yaml` file or you can specify `copy` command inside `docker file`.
    *syntax*:
`copy source destination` in docker file. Or
`volumes:
<folder/path/in/host> : <folder/path/in/container>` in docker-compose

Comment: As of i know Volume can be used to mount a file or a folder between the parent host and the docker container. In my case i want to copy couple of configuration files to one of folder inside the docker container before starting the tomcat server. But if i run a command like below, docker automatically starts the tomcat server as well.                                            $ docker-compose up -d --build

Comment: use docker-file and docker-compose file. in docker file add your copy command as i have said above. Then run docker-compose.yaml file.So before running your container, the configuration can be done at the time of creating image

Comment: I am already using both the docker-compose and dockerfile ..using volume when it will mount the files ? after docker container startup ? because the folder path in container does not exist until the war file gets extracted. When the war file gets extract ? it will extract when the tomcat starts only.

Comment: you can add commad to extract before running

Comment: that would be a good idea. But i have one more issue on that. I am already using CMD to run a sh file to keep the docker container alive after the startup. As per the docker documentation, we cannot use more than one CMD in a dockerfile or in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: you want me to use $ docker-compose run instead of $docker-compose up ? If that is the case, i want to use one command to build all my configuration and start all the services i mentioned in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: No. You can use RUN instead of CMD.

Comment: Instead of COPY you can use ADD. This will archieve the contents.[link](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-add-vs-copy/)

Comment: Yep. Using ADD instead of COPY might work. I will update you once i try this approach. Thanks @Pratheesh M for helping me out on this issue.

Comment: I did try using ADD instead of COPY for copying the WAR file, In addition to this i also added couple of COPY to copy configuration files to the extracted folder before starting the tomcat. But for some reason, when i navigate to the tomcat webapps folder, i see only the configuration files which i copied not the whole extracted files from the WAR file. So i used the RUN to unzip the war file before copying the configuration files. It works now. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot copy the files using docker-compose.yml,but you can use the COPY command in Dockerfile to put the file into the container,
maybe you are confused the path `/app/conf/services.properties` is not a directory that is why the copy didn't happen and the Docker didn't throw error
the other way is you can mount a volume which can be done using the docker-compose.yml

Comment: I think you did not get my scenario correct. Actually I know we can copy files to the Docker container. For me I have to copy the property file to the folder which is going to be extracted from war file when the container starts. In this case it will be tomcat_home/webapps/app/conf/

Comment: you can try putting a script in `CMD` as an entrypoint to copy the config file
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd